# Combining graphic-card and parallel-computation libraries in C++

Tags: visual-studio, qt, opengl, cuda, opencl

I'm working on diploma project that heavily uses mathematical calculations and should present some results in 3D. For these purposes I decided to use CUDA or OpenCL for parallel computation of mathematical part and, most possibly, OpenGL for presenting result. In addition, project should be able to be deployed on clusters (operated by MS Windows), for these purposes project supervisor recommended MPI.

My question is the following: where it is easier to combine all these components, in MS Visual tudio

Main part is CUDA + OpenCL + OpenGL, it will be the core of the project.

P.S. This question is not to star holy-war betwen Qt and MS Visual studio.

Comment: MSVC is an IDE and compiler, it has nothing to do with Qt, CUDA, or OpenGL - all of them can be used inside it.  CUDA is often used with its own nVidia provided IDE anyway.

Comment: For what I know, Qt HAS it's own IDE

Comment: That you don't need to use, in fact Qt Project has provided a VS add-on that gives most of the convenience/tool-chain functionality.  If you are familiar with VS then use it, otherwise try both and see which one you like more.

Comment: @eagle.dan.1349: Yes the Qt project *offers* its own IDE in form of *QtCreator*, but that's just that, an *offer*. You don't have to take it. Also QtCreator is not part of the actual Qt framework. It's a separate product with a separate install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCL is not limited to GPUs, it can be used for parallel programming in clusters as well. Intel for example provides a OpenCL implementation, that is aimed at multicore CPU and clusters.

So my recommendation is to use OpenCL for both GPU computing and clustering. MPI (Message Passing Interface) is mainly a way to communicate between tasks running on separate cluster nodes. It's not so much of a clustering framework by itself.

Comment: Yes, I know that OPenCL also provides a fallback to CPU. But you don't answer the question. TO bring all them together: Qt or Visual studio?

Comment: @eagle.dan.1349 OpenCL does not "provides a fallback to CPU", its a heterogeneous computing platform so it treats all processors that support the OpenCL kernel compiler as first class citizens - CUDA is nVidia GPU only.

Comment: @eagle.dan.1349: Asking "Qt or Visual Studio" is asking like "What should I eat? A Movie at the Cinema or some Book at a Library?". You're comparing completely different things here. Qt is a application development framework. Visual Studio is a development environment and compiler suite. And OpenGL/OpenCL/CUDA are system APIs. Those things are orthogonal to each other and can't replace any of the other. So the only answer I could give you, that makes sense would be a plain "Yes", or "all of them".

Comment: @eagle.dan.1349: Just to make this clear: I got several projects, that are developed using Visual Studio, use Qt as application framework and utilize OpenGL and OpenCL or CUDA.

Comment: @datenwolf: Okay, I see now.